# charts.PerformanceSummary(read) Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, xaxs = "r", log = logaxis) : need finite 'ylim' values

Tags: r, time-series, bloomberg

I extract some stocks data from bloomberg. The dataset has removed NA and been set as time series. However, I'm trying to apply `charts.PerformanceSummary()`. But it shows an error in `plot.window(xlim, ylim, xaxs = "r", log = logaxis)`:

> need finite 'ylim' values

Please tell me what I should do. (I'm just a beginner. Sorry for the unprofessional wording)

Comment: Looks like you are feeding stock prices and not returns to `charts.PerformanceSummary`.